# C++ adaptive mesh with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh

I need to create an adaptive mesh with OpenGL for a square and I have no idea how to.
Basically, I'm creating my square with 4 points.

```
p* p1 = new p(-10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
p* p2 = new p(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
p* p3 = new p(10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f);
p* p4 = new p(-10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f);
```

Then I'd like to be able to create a mesh where I could change the amount of squares that composes the mesh. To do so, I have 2 FOR loops where I'm using glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP) and 4 glVertex3f to create each squares but I don't know how to define the coordinates of these points.

```
for (int j=-10; j<nb; j+=nb)
{ 
for (int i=-10; i<nb; i+=nb)
    { 
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f (i, j, 0);
    glVertex3f (i, j+1, 0);
    glVertex3f (i+1, j+1, 0);
    glVertex3f (i+1, j, 0);
    glEnd();
}   
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you need help with. Unfortunately, the code you've posted is not too relevant to the question, while the actual code you are asking about (the two for loops) is not present.

Comment: @martin_pr I edited my post. The problem with that code is that it creates small squares in my square but I can't modify the amount of square

Comment: Well, yes, each iteration of the internal loop creates a square with edge length 1. Assuming that your `nb` variable is an int initialised to 10, changing it to higher values will make more squares. EDIT: ah, and you probably want `i+=1` and `j+=1` in the for loop.

Comment: @martin_pr Yes you're right, but I'd like to have bigger squares is my nb variable is initialised to 2. With nb = 4, I should have 4 squares while I should have 100 when nb is equal to 100.

Comment: `i<nb` and `j<nb` is your problem in that case.

Comment: Why are you creating those `p…` arrays if you don't use them later on? I'd start with that, because OpenGL immediate mode drawing commands `glBegin`… `glVertex` … `glEnd` **(which you should not use BTW for they are deprecated and have been removed from modern OpenGL)** will just draw stuff but not "magically" transpire something into your arrays.